# How do I use VSCode Tunnels using only a Microsoft account instead of a GitHub account?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, chromebook

I want to code on my school issued Chromebook, however GitHub is blocked on our systems so we aren't allowed to use anything like GitHub CodeSpaces. The best I could find is vscode.dev with remote tunnels which I could use my PC at home to code on. However, it only allows a GitHub account even though there are two options on vscode.dev for either Microsoft.com or GitHub.com login. How could I use the Microsoft login instead of GitHub login so that I can connect to my PC at home on my Chromebook?

I tried to login with my Microsoft account on both instances of VSCode (Chromebook and PC) but the PC only sets up remote tunnels with GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can try the Code Tunnel CLI installation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels
I had a similar problem when trying to connect to the Alpine Linux environment and discovered that it was a problem with the C execution and compilation libs.
But when running the "Code Tunnel" cli the problem was resolved.